# Start the script with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, script, shell-script

I am trying to start the virtual machine(ORACLE VIRTUALBOX) using this script(script name:start_vm001.sh).

```
        START_VM=`/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless --startvm testvm001`
        EXECUTE_VM=`exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --chuid 1001 --exec "$START_VM" -- $START_VM`
        echo $EXECUTE_VM
```

When I run the script without using sudo, Virtual machine was started but When I run the script with sudo, is not start.

```
         username@host1:~$ ./start_vm001.sh, its worked
         username@host1:~$ sudo ./start_vm001.sh its not worked
         Output: sbin/start-stop-daemon: unable to stat Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless   Interface 4.1.12_Ubuntu (C) 2008-2013 Oracle Corporation All rights reserved. Invalid machine name or UUID! (No such file or directory)
```

How to run the script using sudo?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration files for your VMs are stored in the user's home directory under `/home`. You need to create the same folder in `/root` (or symlink them) for sudo to work since virtualbox is looking in the running user's folder for the configuration file.

Comment: hi friend, after I created symbolic link also not worked.